# What is the definition of how to count degrees of freedom?

Tags: definition, degrees-of-freedom

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8626/if-all-conserved-quantities-of-a-system-are-known-can-they-be-explained-by-symme) resulted, rather as by-product, the discussion on how to count degrees of freedom (DOF). I extend that question here:

- Are necessary<sup>1</sup> derivatives such as velocities counted as individual DOFs or together with the respective coordinate<sup>2</sup>?
- Should complex valued DOFs be counted twice as in "two real-valued DOFs" or once as in "one complex-valued DOF"? (I mean, when one does not want to specify this explicitly)

Please answer with some reference, unless it turns out this is actually a matter of taste rather than a strictly defined thing.

---

<sup>1)</sup> I mean those a value of which is *required* as an initial condition
<sup>2)</sup> I count fields in QFT as coordinates as well, while space-time-coordinates are parameters to me, if that matters. I know a field actually has $\infty$ (or rather, $2^\aleph$) DOFs itself, but let's say e.g. "one $\mathbb R^3$ continous DOF" in that case

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TL;DR: In classical point mechanics, (on-shell) degrees of freedom$^1$ (DOF) are the number of initial conditions needed divided by 2.

Perhaps this is simplest to explain via an example: A 1D simple gravity [pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum) with Lagrangian
$$L(\theta,\dot{\theta}) = \frac{m}{2}\ell^2 \dot{\theta}^2 + mg\ell\cos(\theta)$$ 
has *one*  DOF, $\theta$, although its solution $\theta=\theta(t)$ has *two* integration constants. Here, the [generalized coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates) $\theta$ is the angle of the pendulum; $\dot{\theta}$ is the (angular) velocity; and $p_{\theta}:=\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{\theta}}=m\ell^2\dot{\theta}$ is the (angular) momentum. Furthermore, the [configuration space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_space_(physics)) $M\cong\mathbb{S}^1$ is *one* dimensional with *one*  coordinate $\theta$. The tangent bundle $TM$ of the configuration space with *two* coordinates $(\theta,\dot{\theta})$ and the phase space $T^*M$ with  *two* coordinates $(\theta,p_{\theta})$ are both *two* dimensional spaces. In other words, it takes *two* coordinates to fully describe the instantaneous state of the pendulum at a given instant $t$, i.e. *two* initial conditions.

So, to answer the main question: *No,* the corresponding velocity (or momentum in the Hamiltonian formulation) is not counted as a separate DOF.

For generalizations to field and gauge theory, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/100995/2451) Phys.SE post.

References:

1. Landau & Lifshitz, *[Mechanics](http://lccn.loc.gov/60011795)*: see e.g. first page of Chapter 1 or [first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbecX.jpg) of Chapter 2;
2. H. Goldstein, *[Classical Mechanics](http://lccn.loc.gov/79023456)*: see e.g. page 13 or first page of Chapter 8 in both 2nd and 3rd edition;
3. J.V. Jose and E.J. Saletan, *[Classical Dynamics: A Contemporary Approach](http://lccn.loc.gov/97043733)*: see p.18;
4. Wikipedia, either [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_%28mechanics%29) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_%28physics_and_chemistry%29).

--

$^1$ Exception: In the context of the [equipartition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem) the DOF is conventionally the number of phase space variables that appear quadratically in the Hamiltonian.

Comment: hm, L&L states this implicitly en passant, the wikipedia sites both lack citation, and to add confusion, the [german version](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freiheitsgrad) claims `Wird ein Parameter weggelassen, so ist das System nicht mehr eindeutig bestimmt.`, i.e. if a parameter is removed the system is no longer uniquely determined. That would count velocity separately...

Comment: For a 1D pendulum or oscillator you have the second order equation. It can be cased into two ODE of the first order. So there are still two degrees of freedom: $\phi$ and $\dot{\phi}$.

Comment: @Vladimir: that's exactly my question (and preference). Probably it's a matter of taste (or where one studied), but to lessen confusion I guess I should stick with the definition most-used in the literature - it's hard for me to question L&L or Goldstein there :-/ **edit** maybe it's the difference between a mathematical view ($\dot\phi$ is independent of $\phi$) vs an experimental view ($\dot\phi$ just describes the change of $\phi$ but not another particle/field/...)

Comment: Here you have one coordinate (1D motion) but two degrees of freedom. If you manage to separate variables completely, you will have two independent equations with two independent initial data.

Comment: regardless, the physical fact of the 1D pendulum example is that you only need a single scalar variable to describe its state (when it is in its steady state of course!). any other introduced variables are not separate.

Comment: @Bjorn: The configuration space of the 1-D pendulum is clearly 2-D, by which I mean that with both the angle and angular velocity specified I understand the whole past and future behavior of the system. I suspect that what is happening here is that we use "degrees of freedom" in two ways. One way describes the mechanical constrains on a system (i.e. a pendulum swings on one axis only), and the other way counts the dimensionality of the configuration space. Qmechanic's references support the first meaning. I'll be interested in seeing references that use the second.

Comment: @dmckee: mea culpa, I was thinking about a harmonic oscillator when I wrote the last comment, so I agree with you that for a (lossless) pendulum you need to specify two scalars. The same pendulum at the same positions can describe different kinematics depending on the speed (at the specified position for example). So yes, I guess the difference is if you want to describe the dynamic system or the mechanical constraints like you wrote.