Degree of Freedom and Equations of Motion
I am a bit confused about the number of degrees of freedom of a simple pendulum. Is there

only angular displacement, or

angular displacement and angular velocity?


Also, I am a bit confused on the number of equations of motion required to describe this system, is it the same number as the number of degrees of freedom?

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8860/2451

Actually it depends on context.  When we speak of "degrees of freedom" we usually refer to so-called "configuration space" which is the minimum number of variables needed to define the position(s) of the system.  In the case of the pendulum it would be ONE.  However, there is also an analogous set of dimensions called "state space."  This is the (minimum) number of variables needed to describe the system configuration along with the derivatives -- say if you wanted to simulate it. In the case of the pendulum that dimension number would be TWO.  For holonomic systems, the number of dimensions of the state space is twice that of the configuration space.  But for nonholonomic systems, there can be restrictions in the state space that don't equate to the configuration space.
Holonomic systems that can be described by ODEs will have N FIRST order governing differential equations, where N is equal to the dimension of the state space.  Note that the typical way to write the governing equation of a simple pendulum only involves one equation but it is SECOND order.  It can be trivially reduced to two first order equations by defining a second variable equal to the derivative of the position angle.

Oh I see. So in the case of a simple pendulum, two equations of motion, 1) angular displacement 2) angular velocity would be needed to fully describe it?

yes, see my edit that I made while you were typing.

Oh. As a follow-up question, would these equations need to be independent in the sense that they are derived from different methods, or could the equations simply be differentiated to get the other?

Not quite sure how to answer that.  There are various ways to derive and integrate equations of motion.  My preferred way is to use the traditional approach that I'll call $F=ma$ although there is more to it than that.  Using that method for the simple pendulum you get $\ddot{\theta} + \frac{g}{l} \sin{\theta} = 0$.  If you want to numerically integrate this, you define $y = [\theta \ \ \dot{\theta}]$ and the derivative then is $\dot{\bf y} = [\bf{y}(2)  \  \ -\frac{g}{l} \sin{\bf{y}(1)} ]$.   If you want to solve it analytically you assume $\sin{\theta} \approx \theta$ and do it that way.

The only time you would differentiate constraints for integration is for so-called "Differential-Algebraic" problems where the constraint equations are position-based but at least some of the governing equations are second order.  A multi-link pendulum that is constrained in two or more places is an example of this kind of system.  A "four-bar linkage" would fall into that category.

Perhaps let me rephrase my question. If I use the Lagrangian to derive an equation of motion, maybe angular velocity as a function time, can I simply integrate it to find angular displacement as a function of time, getting the two equations needed from the two-dimensional state space, or do I need to use another approach, maybe using forces to find the angular displacement as a function of time. Thank you.

The equation you derive is second-order.  So that is all you need.  But you can solve it in different ways.  "Solving" and "integrating" are kind of the same thing.  In all but the simplest cases, you will not be able to "integrate" the equation in the usual analytic way.

Ok thank you for the help. Apologies since I'm not very familiar with the terminology.

Degrees of freedom is defined as the number of coordinates we need for analysing the motion of that particle. In a simple pendulum there will be $1$ degree of freedom, which would be its angle, if you're making its equations with rectangular coordinates then still there will be $1$ degree of freedom as $x \& y$ are not independant.

But in "rectangular" (Cartesian) co-ordinates the $x$ and $y$ co-ordinates are not independent so there is still only one degree of freedom. Number of degrees of freedom does not depend on the co-ordinate system used.

@gandalf61 sure ill edit my answer.
