# Difference between conserved quantities and constants of motion?

Tags: conservation-laws, hamiltonian-formalism, definition, noethers-theorem, phase-space

In Hamiltonian mechanics, consider extended phase space, the trajectory followed by a particle in that space is formed by an intersection of different $2n$ dimensional surfaces, all of these surfaces are constants of motion, are any symmetric transformations associated with these constants of motion?

What is the difference between constants of motion and conserved quantities formed from symmetric properties?

Answer (score 1):

Concerning OP's title question (v2): A [constant of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_motion) and a [conserved quantity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conserved_quantity) are the same notion.

Comment: so for a system in extended phase space there are 2n constants of motion  implies 2n conserved quantities does this implies 2n symmetric transformations can be done in that extended phase space???????

Comment: Yes, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8626/2451) Phys.SE post.