# Conserved charges generate transformations

Tags: conservation-laws, charge, symmetry, noethers-theorem

Focussing on classical mechanics of a point particle, WLOG since it captures the relevant information for field theory and generalises to the quantum case, how do we show -- in general -- that conserved charges generate the associated transformations of the variables?

Start with infinitesimal transformations $x(t) \rightarrow x(t) + \epsilon \xi(x)$ which, at least for a potential $V(x)$ would seem to imply $p(t) \rightarrow  p + \epsilon m \dot{\xi}(x) = p + \epsilon p \cdot \nabla \xi(x) + \epsilon m \partial_{t} \xi$. Then in one-dimension (for simplicity) the conserved charge associated with this symmetry would be 
$$ \epsilon Q = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{x}} \delta x - \epsilon f $$
where $f$ is the function with which $\mathcal{L} \rightarrow \mathcal{L} + \epsilon\frac{d}{dt}f$ changes by a total derivative.

**Question 1: f will in general depend upon $x$ and $\dot{x}$ but am I supposed to rewrite this in terms of $x$ and $p$?**

Continuing, let's write $ Q= p\xi(x) - f$ and consider whether this generates the transformation through Poisson brackets. We'd like
$$\delta x = \epsilon \{x, Q\} ~~~\textrm{and}~~~ \delta p = \epsilon \{p, Q\} $$
Using the form of Q we get
$$\{x, Q\} = \xi - \frac{\partial f}{\partial p}~~~\textrm{and}~~~ \{p, Q\} = -p \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}.$$
**Question 2: To reproduce the transformations of the variables this would seem to require two conditions**
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial p} = 0 ~~~\textrm{and}~~~ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = m\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial t} + 2p \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x}.$$
**Are these conditions automatically satisfied for some reason? Must they be imposed for consistency? What happens if they're not?**

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24596/is-the-converse-of-noethers-first-theorem-true-every-conservation-law-has-a-sy).

Comment: Thank you, Cosmas. I wonder if you have any thoughts on the current question? I mean I know the statement that charges generate transformations is true but how can it be proved in this way?

Comment: No thoughts beyond linked and linked therein. Your time-dependent surmise appears obscure and *not* canonical. Perhaps [the answer to this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/499113/how-to-check-if-a-generating-function-produces-an-identity-transformation-withou/499382#499382) might be helpful; perhaps not.

Comment: [More linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/461737/why-are-symmetries-in-phase-space-generated-by-functions-that-leave-the-hamilton).